# Using a mapbox expression to get feature id

Tags: expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using data driven styling to style a Mapbox vector layer for a choropleth map. However, rather than getting the data strictly from the layer properties, I need to use statistic data from a separate object (pulled from our database). This separate object contains one statistic value for each polygon in the vector layer. The object maps the stat values to the vector layer polygons by a variable called "GEOID". In order to marry the polygon with its data, I would like to use a Mapbox expression to get the GEOID value from each polygon in the vector layer and pass this id to a separate function to get the statistic value for the polygon having this GEOID. Is this possible?

```
 vectorLayer: {
    id: "fooLayer",
    type: "fill",
    "source-layer": "foo-layer-dvf1ci",
    paint: {
      "fill-color": [
        "rgba",
        100,100,100,
        this.getStatForDistrict(["get", "GEOID"])]
      ]
    }
  },

getStatForDistrict(districtId) {
  console.log("districtId: " + districtId);
  let alphaValue = fetchDataForThisDistrictFromDatabase(districtId)
  return alphaValue;
},
```

I see that currently, I am passing ["get", "GEOID"] into the function getStatForDistrict when what I actually need is to pass the computed Mapbox expression.

More on Mapbox-GL's paint property: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-property

More on Mapbox-GL's expressions syntax: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you able to spell it out a little bit more, perhaps with some more code?

Comment: Thanks Steve. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not any way to call arbitrary functions from within expressions, which look up data that doesn't exist within the feature in question.

There are several ways to make choropleths. I'd suggest you start by looking at the [mapbox-choropleth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-choropleth) library.

Comment: Thank you.This looks great, for cases where the statistic data is stored in a csv file. I have aggregation buckets from an elasticsearch query. I'm looking at the js files in this github project, trying to figure out how to modify the code to work with an array of objects where each object has a single key value pair where the key matches one of the ids from the mapbox layer's feature set and thev value is a statistic.

Comment: Interesting. That mapbox-choropleth library does in fact use Mapbox expressions to reference data from a separate object. The library uses the Mapbox's "match" operator to find the value in the separate object corresponding to each polygon's id. I managed to create our choropleths using a similar approach and will post my solution shortly.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that library...:) I guess I didn't totally understand what you were asking.